# How to make the tip of a QSlider in PySide2 look like a triangle?

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2

[image: desired output]

I want to make the end of QSlider triangular like in the image above, but I couldn't do it. When I use the code `self.mindelayclicki.setTickPosition(QSlider.TicksBelow)` it becomes triangular, but I want it to be included in the stylesheet I added, and I don't want it to be in the red area:

[image: red area]

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QSlider
from PySide2.QtGui import Qt

from sys import exit, argv


class MyWin(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(400, 400)
        self.mindelayclicki = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.mindelayclicki.setGeometry(20, 100, 350, 25)
        self.mindelayclicki.setStyleSheet("""
            QSlider::groove:horizontal {
                height: 8px;
                margin: 0px;
                background-color: #E7EAEA;
                border:1px solid #D6D6D6;
            }
            QSlider::handle:horizontal {
                height: 20px;
                width: 12px;
                margin: -12px 0px -12px 0px;
                background-color: #007AD9;
            }
                """)
        self.show()
app = QApplication(argv)
window = MyWin()
exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: When you use stylesheets on complex widgets (like QSlider) the result is that they will be shown using a very basic and elementary style that is only altered by the contents of the stylesheet. This means that using the QSS above you will not get the default behavior anymore. Note that this is not just specific to Qt, a quite similar behavior happens in common web browsers too. If you want to show the slider (and its handle) with a specific shape, you can only do that by completely implementing its painting on your own.